# Protection against maliciously altered files

Tags: security

Regarding [this](https://superuser.com/questions/849845/what-is-the-value-of-md5-checksums-if-the-md5-hash-itself-could-potentially-also) question, what can then be used to verify the authenticity of a file transferred using Internet if the uploader and downloader do not know (and can't meet) each other in person?

Asymmetric encryption (digital signing?) might not work here because the entity which can potentially modify the hash available on a web page can also replace the available public key of original key pair with a new one used for signing the malicious file.

**EDIT1**: What methods, short of meeting in person, might be employed to make sure that a one-to-many file transfer where signing with recipient's key is not practically possible (because the file to be transferred is going to be downloaded by many, yet unknown people) is not altered by a third party?

Comment: Isn't this more of a philosophical question? And anyway, I'm not sure I understand what specifically your premises are. You say that a malicious entity could modify the hash available on a web page, but does that mean you assume that the uploader is the bad guy? And why would a malicious entity be able to sign a file? Isn't that the uploader's responsibility?

Comment: I meant that if public-private key pair is used to validate the file; the malicious entity compromises the server, replaces original file with the altered one, signs the altered file with a private key and replaces the original public key given in a public-accessible place (like hashes are provided in download page). Edited the question to make it more precise.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed because of being unclear. To me it only seems unclear for the people not familiar with encryption and signing.

Comment: You are mixing two things: encryption is done with the public key of the recipient and ensures that no one else can read the content - seems not applicable in your case? Signing is done with the private key of the sender and ensures that the recipient can check that the content was not altered - which is what you want. You are right, you need a secure channel to transfer your public key to the recipients. Normally another way is chosen: you let a well-known CA sign your certificate. If the recipients trust the CA they know your certificate is valid.

Comment: I was wondering if there was some lesser known technology other than a CA, although that is a last resort. Using a Certificate Authority might not be possible for everyone in every situation (say, due to economic restrictions).